# Quicksort in python

Tags: python, quicksort

The below written code for quicksort is not sorting a list properly. There must be some logical flaw in the code. Can anybody please review the code?

```
def quicksort(aList, start, last):
    i = start + 1
    j = start + 1
    pivot = aList[start]
    while j <= last and pivot > aList[j]:
        if pivot > aList[j]:
            temp = aList[i]
            aList[i] = aList[j]
            aList[j] = temp
            i = i + 1
        j = j + 1

    temp = aList[start]
    aList[start] = aList[i-1]
    aList[i-1] = temp
    if i - start > 2:
        quicksort(aList, start, i-2)
    if last - i > 0:
        quicksort(aList, i, last)


aList = [2, 5, 3, 95, 68, 75, 29, 52]
quicksort(aList, 0, len(aList)-1)
print aList
```

Comment: Please tell us what is wrong. What do you expect, what is the result of your code?

Comment: Here's a hint to help you figure out what is wrong: add `print aList` immediately before the line that says `temp=aList[start]`

Comment: Also, take a look at [PEP-8 (Style Guide for Python code)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) - don't use tabs for indentation - use four spaces per level. Use whitespace around operators. Avoid unnecessary parentheses. And get to know tuple packing and unpacking: `alist[i], alist[j] = alist[j], alist[i]` is much cooler.

Comment: I am getting the final list as "[2, 3, 5, 52, 68, 29, 75, 95]
" which is not properly sorted. input is given in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def quicksort(aList, start, last):
  i = start + 1
  j = start + 1
  pivot = aList[start]
  while j <= last:
    if pivot > aList[j]:
      temp = aList[i]
      aList[i] = aList[j]
      aList[j] = temp
      i = i + 1
    j = j + 1

  temp = aList[start]
  aList[start] = aList[i-1]
  aList[i-1] = temp
  if i - start > 2:
    quicksort(aList, start, i-2)
  if last - i > 0:
    quicksort(aList, i, last)
```

try this!

yopy have given another version of quick sort.

the key of quick sort is the choose of pivot, in your code the pivot is the first element of array, to get a better average performance, you can choose pivot by random.

Answer (score 0):

**Please check this:**

```
def quicksort(aList, start, last):
    i = start + 1
    j = last
    pivot = aList[start]
    while i <= j:
        if pivot > aList[j]:
            aList[i], aList[j] = aList[j], aList[i]
            i = i + 1
        elif pivot < aList[j]:
            j = j - 1

    aList[start], aList[i-1] = aList[i-1], aList[start]

    if i - start > 2:
        quicksort(aList, start, i-2)
    if last - i > 0:
        quicksort(aList, i, last)


aList = [2, 5, 3, 95, 68, 75, 29, 52]
quicksort(aList, 0, len(aList)-1)
print aList
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 5, 29, 52, 68, 75, 95]
```

Comment: this works .. although I used a different logic. both i & j grows incrementally unlike ur code where j decreases and I increases ..

Comment: Why check `i <= j` in the if statements within the while `i <= j` loop? It looks like that will always pass as true, or have I missed something?

Comment: removed thanks, it was redundant. i was fixing the snippet and forgot to remove it.